# What instruments were used to record the Doctor Who theme -- originally?

Tags: doctor-who, theme-music

We all know the theme music for *Doctor Who* has had the same tune and general sound since the show first aired in 1963, and has been rerecorded several times over that period -- most recently, when Jodie Whittaker took over the TARDIS.  I've seen video of someone performing (a version of) the theme on a synthesizer, but synthesizers as we know them (even the Moog and Korg) didn't yet exist when the theme was first recorded.

There's an obvious theremin line for the primary melody, of course, but the rest of the sound doesn't seem to be conventional instruments (strings, woodwinds, percussion, etc.) to my ear.

What instruments were used in recording the *original* theme music for the show when it first aired in 1963?

Comment: Crucially, was a screwdriver involved? Because if so, there's you first sonic screwdriver right there.

Comment: Very nice piece explaining the process on wikipedia:  [Doctor Who theme music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_theme_music#History)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The theme "Doctor Who" (nee "Dr. Who") was originally composed using electronic components like test tone generators, some filtering circuits, and a low frequency oscillator—in effect using a cobbled-together analog proto-synthesizer. Sounds were created and recorded to tape, which was then spliced by hand and constructed manually into the song. This version was **not** the first broadcast, though. The first broadcast version used more or less the same techniques as the first recording.

"[A History of the Doctor Who Theme](https://web.archive.org/web/20100107054505/http://markayres.rwsprojects.co.uk/DWTheme.htm)"

Comment: Nice, so synthetic sounds spliced together -- like *The In Sound From Way Out*, an album of tape-splice music from around 1970.  That explains why even the old episodes sound so modern -- they essentially stole tech from the future to record the theme!

Comment: Which is, @ZeissIkon, the _only_ appropriate way to do it for a show about time traveling.

Comment: Completely agree, @FreeMan.

Comment: Honestly, I always thought it was made with a [theremin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theremin).

Comment: @RBarryYoung The primary theme line in the older series sounds a great deal like a theremin to me as well, but it's clear to me that "bouncy" sounds couldn't be made on any theremin I've heard.  I was thinking there might have been an electric hammer dulcimer or some such, but tone generators and tape splicing makes more sense.

Comment: @ZeissIkon While I do not have personal familiarity with proto-synthesizers, I do have some experience recording with early analog synths (like old enough to require 'patch cords' to connect the LFO to the filter bank, etc.). [Glissando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glissando) and [portamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portamento) transitions between notes were possible with some early analog synthesizers… I am not competent with the electronics, but the theremin-like sound *may* have been created sans-theremin.

Comment: @Lexible What I was saying is that some of the sounds almost certainly *can't* be created on a theremin.  Specifically the sharp-attack, quick-decay bass line.  The theremin sound was fairly easy to imitate, the earliest synthesizers were effectively a theremin with keys producing defined steps in frequency instead of "slides" from continuously variable body capacitance; just needed that sawtooth waveform in the oscillator to have the sound.